# Host the django on https in ec2 for production with a free SSL certificate for it. Without a domain

Tags: django, http, amazon-ec2, https, communication

I have a django deployed on aws and i have a frontned react js running on a https endpoint server. The frontend allows only https requests to be made. But when i run the django python manage.py runserver in my "production" of django app on ec2 i only get to use http not https.

So, is there any way to get a free SSL  certificate for that django app running on ec2 public ip without a domain.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most famous opensource and free ssl certificate provider is Let's Encrypt and as of now they dont have an option to provide certs for an ip address (without a domain)

I would suggest you to deploy your app in the ec2 instance using NGINX + Gunicorn and use a free domain like `.tk` etc.

Then you can use Certbot by Let's encrypt and have https up and running.

Let me know if you want me to explain the process in more detail.

Comment: Yes please explain in detail